# How do I convert split string (string array) to double in C#?

Tags: c#, string, double

The question:

8 children's height is being checked, and inserted.
Insert 8 double values into the console, and make an algorithm to find out the lowest height & the maximum height.

So this is what I've done:

```
class work1 {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        string[] height = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        double[] heightInDouble = new Double[height.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i <= height.Length; i++) {
            heightInDouble[i] = (double) height[i]; // line 20
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Highest: " + heightInDouble.Max() + " Lowest: " + heightInDouble.Min());
    }
}
```

The results:

> Error: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'double' (20)

How can I convert a **string** to a **double value**?

Comment: You need to parse each string, e.g. with `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`. Look into those methods and see if that helps you. Note that if they're meant to be integers (ints) it's odd to create a `double` array. I suggest you either change the name or the type. (Actually, I'd change the name anyway to show what they're meant to be: heights.)

Comment: The whole this is quite simpler with Linq, `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(double.Parse);` That's if you can trust your inputs.

Comment: @nawfal Good idea, but I must do it from my own knowledge, It was a simple problem in the Computer Science class

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly cast from string to double.  Use `double.Parse`:

```
realInts[i] = double.Parse( ints[i] );
```

You may also want to use `TryParse`, as it's not certain here that the string is actually a number:

```
double parsedValue;
realInts[i] = double.TryParse(ints[i], out parsedValue) ? parsedValue : 0;
```

One more note: you could simplify the syntax by using a Linq expression chain:

```
double parsedVal;
double[] realInts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')
    .Select(str => double.TryParse(str, out parsedVal) ? parsedVal : 0)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: double.Parse() is an awesome solution, thanks. I always wondered with is the parse(), going to read more about it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] ints = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        double[] realInts = new Double[ints.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i <= ints.Length; i++)
        {
            double val;
            if (Double.TryParse(ints[i], out val))
            {
                realInts[i] = val; // line 20
            }
            else
            {
                // Unable to parse
                realInts[i] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
class work1
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string[] height = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        double[] heightInDouble = new Double[height.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < height.Length; i++)
        {
            heightInDouble[i] = Convert.ToDouble(height[i]); // line 20
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Highest: " + heightInDouble.Max() + " Lowest: " + heightInDouble.Min());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```